# Call appropriate function based on the type of objects

Tags: java, inheritance, casting, overloading

I am writing a 2d physics engine for fun.

I have written different classes for different shapes `BoxObject` is a rectangle, `BallObject` is a circle and `LineObject` a line. All of these implement the `PhysicsObject` interface.

All objects that are being simulated reside in a list.

```
public static List<PhysicsObject> objects = new ArrayList<PhysicsObject>();
```

All of these objects need to be checked for collision with one another.

`Collision` class contains methods named `penetrationData` to get penetration data for all possible type pairs, e.g. `penetrationData(BoxObject a, BallObject b)` and `penetrationData(BallObject a, LineObject b)` etc. here's what it looks like.

```
package com.optimus.game.physics;

public class Collision {

    // Default - no collision
    public static float[] penetrationData(PhysicsObject a, PhysicsObject b) {
        return null;
    }

    // Line vs Circle
    public static float[] penetrationData(LineObject line, BallObject ball) {
        float distance = line.distance(ball.x, ball.y);
        if (Math.abs(distance) > ball.radius) {
            return null;
        }
        float penetration = ball.radius - Math.abs(distance);
        float normalX = line.perpendicularX();
        float normalY = line.perpendicularY();
        return new float[] {normalX, normalY, penetration};
    }

    // Circle vs Line
    public static float[] penetrationData(BallObject ball, LineObject line) {
        float[] data = penetrationData(line, ball);
        // reverse the normal
        if (data != null) {
            data[0] = -data[0];
            data[1] = -data[1];
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Circle vs Circle
    public static float[] penetrationData(BallObject a, BallObject b) {

        // Vector from A to B
        float normalX = b.x - a.x;
        float normalY = b.y - a.y;
        float penetration = 0;

        // calculate the penetration and normal direction
        // ...
        // ... (code skipped)

        return new float[] {normalX, normalY, penetration};
    }

    // Rect vs Rect
    public static float[] penetrationData(BoxObject a, BoxObject b) {
        // Vector from A to B
        float normalX = b.x - a.x;
        float normalY = b.y - a.y;
        float penetration = 0;

        // calculate the penetration and normal direction
        // ...
        // ... (code skipped)

        return new float[] {normalX, normalY, penetration};
    }

    // Rect vs Circle
    public static float[] penetrationData(BoxObject box, BallObject ball) {
        // Vector from A to B
        float normalX = ball.x - (box.x + box.width / 2f);
        float normalY = ball.y - (box.y + box.height / 2f);
        float penetration = 0;

        // calculate the penetration and normal direction
        // ...
        // ... (code skipped)

        return new float[] {normalX, normalY, penetration};
    }

    // Circle vs Rect
    public static float[] penetrationData(BallObject ball, BoxObject box) {
        float[] data = penetrationData(box, ball);
        // reverse the normal
        if (data != null) {
            data[0] = -data[0];
            data[1] = -data[1];
        }
        return data;
    }


}
```

And I check for collision like...

```
public static void checkAndResolveCollisions(List<PhysicsObject> objects) {
    // check collision between all objects in a list
    // list of objects can contain BallObject, LineObject and
    // BoxObject all of which implement PhysicsObject

    // loop over all possible pairs
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < objects.size(); j++) {

            // here I want that apt function is called based on type
            // but objects.get(int i) always returns a PhysicsObject
            float[] data = Collision.penetrationData(objects.get(i), objects.get(j));

            // data = null implies no overlap
            if (data == null) {
                continue;
            }

            // Calculate relative velocity in terms of the normal direction
            float normalX = data[0];
            float normalY = data[1];
            float penetration = data[2];

            // Resolve the collision along the normal
            // ...
            // ... (code skipped)

        }
    }
}
```

But It does not work and `penetrationData` returns `null` every time...

What does work is if I get penetration data like this, but this code stinks, I can tell just by looking at it...

```
// here is what works, but I know is bad java code
float[] data = getAptPenetrationData(objects.get(i), objects.get(j));
```

Where `getAptPenetrationData` is a generic function that typecasts and then calls apt function

```
// generic function that calls others
    public static float[] getAptPenetrationData(PhysicsObject a, PhysicsObject b) {
        // bad java code...
        boolean aIsBall = a instanceof BallObject;
        boolean aIsBox = a instanceof BoxObject;
        boolean aIsLine = a instanceof LineObject;

        boolean bIsBall = b instanceof BallObject;
        boolean bIsBox = b instanceof BoxObject;
        boolean bIsLine = b instanceof LineObject;

        float[] data = null;
        // circle vs circle
        if (aIsBall && bIsBall) {
            data = Collision.penetrationData((BallObject)a, (BallObject)b);
        // box vs box
        } else if (aIsBox && bIsBox) {
            data = Collision.penetrationData((BoxObject)a, (BoxObject)b);
        // box vs circle
        } else if (aIsBox && bIsBall) {
            data = Collision.penetrationData((BoxObject)a, (BallObject)b);
        // circle vs box
        } else if (aIsBall && bIsBox) {
            data = Collision.penetrationData((BallObject)a, (BoxObject)b);
        // circle vs line
        } else if (aIsBall && bIsLine) {
            data = Collision.penetrationData((BallObject)a, (LineObject)b);
        // line vs circle
        } else if (aIsLine && bIsBall) {
            data = Collision.penetrationData((LineObject)a, (BallObject)b);
        }
        return data;
    }
```

I must be missing something and there must be a better way to do what I am trying to do. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**Edit:**

According to Zim-Zam's suggestion, collision is now resolved like this...

```
public static void checkAndResolveCollisions(List<PhysicsObject> objects) {
    // check collision between all objects in a list
    // list of objects can contain BallObject, LineObject and
    // BoxObject all of which implement PhysicsObject

    // loop over all possible pairs
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < objects.size(); j++) {

            // does not work, goes into infinite recursion
            // still calls PhysicsObject.penetrationData(PhysicsObject)
            float[] data = objects.get(i).penetrationData(objects.get(j));

            // data = null implies no overlap
            if (data == null) {
                continue;
            }

            // Calculate relative velocity in terms of the normal direction
            float normalX = data[0];
            float normalY = data[1];
            float penetration = data[2];

            // Resolve the collision along the normal
            // ...
            // ... (code skipped)

        }
    }
}
```

but it only works if I add below method signatures to `PhysicsObject` interface

```
public PenetrationData penetrationData(PhysicsObject other);
public PenetrationData penetrationData(BallObject other);
public PenetrationData penetrationData(BoxObject other);
public PenetrationData penetrationData(LineObject other);
```

which is still not ideal cause every time I implement a new `PhysicsObject` I'll have to change the interface.

*PhysicsObject implementations (only `penetrationData` functions) -*

**BallObject.java**

```
public class BallObject implements PhysicsObject {

    @Override
    public float[] penetrationData(PhysicsObject other) {
        return other.penetrationData(this);
    }
    @Override
    public float[] penetrationData(LineObject line) {
        return Collision.penetrationData(this, line);
    }
    @Override
    public float[] penetrationData(BoxObject box) {
        return Collision.penetrationData(this, box);
    }
    @Override
    public float[] penetrationData(BallObject ball) {
        return Collision.penetrationData(this, ball);
    }

    // ... rest of the code
}
```

**BoxObject.java**

```
public class BoxObject implements PhysicsObject {

    @Override
    public float[] penetrationData(PhysicsObject other) {
        return other.penetrationData(this);
    }
    @Override
    public float[] penetrationData(LineObject line) {
        return null; // not implemented
    }
    @Override
    public float[] penetrationData(BoxObject box) {
        return Collision.penetrationData(this, box);
    }
    @Override
    public float[] penetrationData(BallObject ball) {
        return Collision.penetrationData(this, ball);
    }

    // ... rest of the code
}
```

**LineObject.java**

```
public class LineObject implements PhysicsObject {

    @Override
    public float[] penetrationData(PhysicsObject other) {
        return other.penetrationData(this);
    }
    @Override
    public float[] penetrationData(LineObject line) {
        return null; // not implemented
    }
    @Override
    public float[] penetrationData(BoxObject box) {
        return null; // not implemented
    }
    @Override
    public float[] penetrationData(BallObject ball) {
        return Collision.penetrationData(this, ball);
    }

    // ... rest of the code
}
```

Comment: It would be better to have a common interface/abstract class for your objects and use generic methods from the interface/abstract class instead of doing all this `if-else` comparisons.

Comment: From Effective C++, by Scott Meyers :

*"Anytime you find yourself writing code of the form "if the object is of type T1, then do something, but if it's of type T2, then do something else,"* slap yourself.

Comment: @Baadshah I would... but it would not make my code better... your suggestions might...

Comment: @Baadshah Unfortunately, manual type dispatch is often necessary, even in Python where everyone says it's evil. Like all design decisions, there are tradeoffs.

Comment: @Optimus see Luiggi Mendoza comment.

Comment: seen it... Looks like i'll need to read up on generics first...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already noted, you need double dispatch. However, I wouldn't advise the heavyweight and boilerplate-ridden *Visitor* pattern. You should implement your own dispatch system in Java. For example, build a map from object pair to penetration data calculator. Then instead of a lot of `instanceof`s, you'll have a lot of `map.put()`. You can even avoid the repetition of `put` by employing a *varargs* method, which may be used to fake a *map literal*:

```
static Map<ObjPair, CollisionCalc> map(Object... kvs) {
   final Map<ObjPair, CollisionCalc> ret = new HashMap<>();
   for (int i = 0;;i < kvs.length) 
     ret.put((ObjPair)kvs[i++], (CollisionCalc)kvs[i++]);
   return ret;
}
```

On the client side this should look like the following:

```
public static float[] penetrationData(PhyObject o1, PhyObject o2) {
  return map.get(new ObjPair(o1, o2)).penetrationData(o1, o2);
}
```

Comment: I tried Visitor pattern and found it impractical, coz i do need to add more implementations of PhysicsObject in the future and then i'll be forced to change my interface. I finally took this approach... thanks...

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use a [multimethod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch) extension, e.g. the [Java MultiMethod Framework](http://igm.univ-mlv.fr/~forax/works/jmmf/), which automatically performs parameter downcasts at runtime.  For example, `Collision.penetrationData(physicaObject obj1, physicsObject obj2)` will automatically be resolved to `Collision.penetrationData(ballObject obj1, squareObject obj2)` or whatever.

Another option is to put a `physicsObject1.resolvePenetrationData(physicsObject obj1)` method in each `physicsObject` subclass - this will automatically determine the actual type of `physicsObject1`.  Then in `resolvePenetrationData` you can determine the actual type of the `physicsObject obj1` parameter and call the appropriate static method.  You'll still be manually determining the type of one of your objects, but the type of the other object is resolved automatically.  Or you can automatically resolve both object types by overloading `resolvePenetrationData` to accept a `PhysicsObject` parameter, and a `BallObject` parameter, etc.  Call `resolvePenetrationData` twice, once per parameter,

```
class BallObject {
    float[] resolvePenetrationData(PhysicsObject obj1) {
        return obj1.resolvePenetrationData(this);
    }
    float[] void resolvePenetrationData(BallObject obj1) {
        return Collision.penetrationData(this, obj1);
    }
    float[] resolvePenetrationData(SquareObject obj1) {
        return Collision.penetrationData(this, obj1);
    }
    //etc
}
```

Comment: well one of the type still needs to be resolved... because I am iterating over a List<PhysicsObject> which returns a PhysicsObject... so `ball.resolvePenetrationData(square)` will still call `BallObject.resolvePenetrationData(PhysicsObject)` ...

Comment: @Optimus The `resolvePenetrationData(PhysicsObject obj1)` method calls `resolvePenetrationObject` on `obj1`, which automatically resolves its type.

Comment: PhysicsObjects are not resolved to their types... this causes an infinite recursion... sadly...

Comment: @Optimus Can you edit your question with the code you're using?

Comment: It does work after I add `public float[] penetrationData(PhysicsObject other);
 public float[] penetrationData(BallObject other);
 public float[] penetrationData(BoxObject other);
 public float[] penetrationData(LineObject other);` to PhysicsObject interface... it is not ideal... but will do for now...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there isn't really. Java's virtual methods provide single dispatch, but what you need is double dispatch.

One alternative to the obvious approach of using a giant switch/if else is to do a Visitor like pattern. However, that may or may not actually be better depending on your needs.

Comment: @Hovercraft I actually just added that.